# Apply an interface over a concrete type

Tags: types, julia

I am working with images that have color components, spatial components and surface normal  components. So I defined a StaticArray of 9 components.

```
using StaticArrays
const RGBDN{T} = SVector{9,T}
const RGBDNImage{T} = Matrix{RGBDN{T}} where T<:Number
```

I want to adapt and use some methods from [ImageSegmentation.jl](https://github.com/JuliaImages/ImageSegmentation.jl). Some of these methods accept a datatype derived from the [Colorant](https://github.com/JuliaGraphics/ColorTypes.jl) type.

There is a better method than using

```
struct RGBDN{T} <: Colorant{T,9}
   data::SVector{9,T}
end
```

and then using something like [Delegate.jl](https://github.com/Jeffrey-Sarnoff/Delegate.jl) or [TypedDelegation.jl](https://github.com/JuliaArbTypes/TypedDelegation.jl) in order to have the behaviour of an Array but at the same  type being a Colorant without re-implementing everything.

Thank you!

Comment: Any specific functionality from ImageSegmentation.jl that you need? You could specialize free/outer functions to your concrete type, but that would depend on how the code in ImSeg is written.

Comment: I have no answer for this, but I do wonder from your question if you're [overthinking your high-level structure](https://caseymuratori.com/blog_0015) a bit too much in the first place. Code a solution first, use locally scoped / easily refactorable blocks as much as possible, see what patterns emerge or tend to be reused, tidy up accordingly and usefully. Apologies if I misunderstood what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. I've already implemented as I described in the answer and it is working. Delegate.jl is really easy to use and I had to write very little code. I wanted to adapt the implementation of the Felzenszwalb algorithm, as described in [Graph-based Segmentation for Colored 3D Laser Point Clouds](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5650459). And I want to be able to use all the handy functions that ImageSegmentation.jl has. I made the question because I wanted to know if it there is a preferred way to solve this issue.